# CakePHP querying table that doesn't have a controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller labeled OrdersController, but I have an additional table for the items that make up an order.

So my two tables are

```
//orders
id  |  email  | date   |  total | order_status

//order_items
id  | product_num | quantity  | total  | item_status
```

In this case order_numbers.id is the foreign key which references orders.id.

How can I make this foreign key connection in cakephp when order_items isn't a controller itself?

I try to query it but I get an error and it shows cakephp trying to query order.item_status (it's not trying to query the order_items table)

```
$order_status = $this->Order->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array('order_items.item_status' => "Not Filled")
));
```

I want to see if all of the items in a particular order have been filled so then I can mark the order table status as being filled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the models, something like in your
**order_item model**

```
class OrderItem extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Order' => array(
            'className'    => 'Order',
            'foreignKey'   => 'order_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Can I have an order_item model without having OrderItemsController?

Answer (score 0):

Your model layer is completely independent of your controller layer. You can have as many or as few models for your controller and it does not matter what either your controller or models are named (of course adhere to [CakePHP's Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)). By default, if you have a `PostsController` and you do not define the `uses` member variable, CakePHP will try to load the `Post` model.